# Compile Error: Syntax error

Tags: vba, syntax

Can someone please let me know where the error is in the below code?

Is it that the list is too long? I don't know why I'm getting the syntax error.
Grateful for any help you can provide.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tabArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    tabArray = Array("B3","B4","G3","F7","H7","I7","J7","F8","H8","I8","J8","F9","H9","I9","J9","F10","H10","I10","J10","F11","H11","I11","J11","F12","H12","I12","J12","F13","H13","I13","J13","F14","H14","I14","J14","F15","H15","I15","J15","F19,"I19","C23","F23","C27","C29","C36","F37","I36","C37","C38","C40","C41","C42","G46","H46","G47","H47","G48","H48","C77","C80","C85","D85","C86","D86","C87","D87","C89","D89","C90","D90","C91","D91","C92","D92","C93","D93","C94","D94","C95","D95","C96","D96","G90","J90","G91","J91","G92","J92","G93","J93","G94","J94","G95","J95","C99","C103","C104","C107","C111","C115","D115","H115","C116","D116","H116","C117","D117","H117","C118","D118","H118","C119","D119","H119","A124","A125","A126","A127","A128","A129","A130","A131","A132","A133","A134","A135","A136","A137")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(tabArray) To UBound(tabArray)
        If tabArray(i) = Target.Address(0, 0) Then
            If i = UBound(tabArray) Then
                Me.Range(tabArray(LBound(tabArray))).Select
            Else
                Me.Range(tabArray(i + 1)).Select
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: VB uses newline as it's line delimiter, so having all the code on one line as displayed won't work.

Comment: Double quotes are missing `"F19,"I19"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing closing double quotes:
`,"F19,"I19",`

I fixed it:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tabArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    tabArray = Array("B3","B4","G3","F7","H7","I7","J7","F8","H8","I8","J8","F9","H9","I9","J9","F10","H10","I10","J10","F11","H11","I11","J11","F12","H12","I12","J12","F13","H13","I13","J13","F14","H14","I14","J14","F15","H15","I15","J15","F19","I19","C23","F23","C27","C29","C36","F37","I36","C37","C38","C40","C41","C42","G46","H46","G47","H47","G48","H48","C77","C80","C85","D85","C86","D86","C87","D87","C89","D89","C90","D90","C91","D91","C92","D92","C93","D93","C94","D94","C95","D95","C96","D96","G90","J90","G91","J91","G92","J92","G93","J93","G94","J94","G95","J95","C99","C103","C104","C107","C111","C115","D115","H115","C116","D116","H116","C117","D117","H117","C118","D118","H118","C119","D119","H119","A124","A125","A126","A127","A128","A129","A130","A131","A132","A133","A134","A135","A136","A137")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(tabArray) To UBound(tabArray)
        If tabArray(i) = Target.Address(0, 0) Then
            If i = UBound(tabArray) Then
                Me.Range(tabArray(LBound(tabArray))).Select
            Else
                Me.Range(tabArray(i + 1)).Select
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I truly appreciate your help.